# How to get both the old and new value of an Orchard.Rules Event Published

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I can create a new rule with an event of "Published", and I can fetch the value of a given part, say the AutoroutePart. But how do I get the old value?

I want to compare the two values, and if it has changed, I want to create a new Rewrite Rule based on that.

My aim is to make a simple URL Tracker module, which allows you to change any content item's route with no worries about SEO.

It will be depending on the Orchard.Module.Contrib.RewriteRules by Sébastien Ros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't Published has nothing to do with old values. What you want is the Versionned event for when a new content version is created. Because a user could create a new version and publish it in two different steps. If you still wanted to access old versions during a Published event then you might need a custom event with custom tokens.

Or maybe you could file a feature request so that we provide a new token to access previous versions of a content item. Something like {Content.Versions:0} for latest and {Content.Versions:1} for the one just before the latest. Just an idea. This would also solve you initial question.

Or even better, you could implement it and do a pull request.